# TransientDataAccessResourceException - R2DBC pgdb connection remains in idle in transaction

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, database-connection, r2dbc-postgresql

I have a spring-boot application where using webflux and r2dbc-postgres. I have discovered a strange issue when trying to do some db operations in a `flatMap()`.

Code example:

```
@Transactional
public Mono<Void> insertDummyFooBars() {
        return Flux.fromIterable(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 260).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .log()
                .flatMap(i -> this.repository.save(FooBar.builder().foo("test-" + i).build()))
                .log()
                .concatMap(i -> this.repository.findAll())
                .then();
    }
```

It seems like `flatMap` can process max `256` elements in batches. (`Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE` default value is `256`). So when I tried to run the code above (with 260 elements) I've got an exception - `TransientDataAccessResourceException` and the following message:

`Cannot exchange messages because the request queue limit is exceeded; nested exception is io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$RequestQueueException`

There is no `Releasing R2DBC Connection` after this exception. The pgdb connection/session remains in `idle in transaction` state and the app is not able to run properly when pool max size is reached and all of the connections are in `idle in transaction` state. I think the connection should be released even if an exception happened or not.

If I use `concatMap` instead of `flatMap` it works as expected - no exception, connection released! It's also ok with flatMap when the elements are less than or equal to 256.

Is it possible to force pgdb connection closure? What should I do If I have lot of db operations in `flatMap` like this? Should I replace all of them with `concatMap`? Is there a global solution for this?

Versions:
Postgres: 12.6, Spring-boot: 2.7.6

[Demo project](https://github.com/Spire6/Idle-in-transaction-demo)

LOG:

```
2022-12-08 16:32:13.092  INFO 17932 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] reactor.Flux.Iterable.1                  : | onNext(256)
2022-12-08 16:32:13.092 DEBUG 17932 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] o.s.r2dbc.core.DefaultDatabaseClient     : Executing SQL statement [INSERT INTO foo_bar (foo) VALUES ($1)]
2022-12-08 16:32:13.114  INFO 17932 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] reactor.Flux.FlatMap.2                   : onNext(FooBar(id=258, foo=test-1))
2022-12-08 16:32:13.143 DEBUG 17932 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] o.s.r2dbc.core.DefaultDatabaseClient     : Executing SQL statement [SELECT foo_bar.* FROM foo_bar]
2022-12-08 16:32:13.143  INFO 17932 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] reactor.Flux.Iterable.1                  : | request(1)
2022-12-08 16:32:13.143  INFO 17932 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] reactor.Flux.Iterable.1                  : | onNext(257)
2022-12-08 16:32:13.144 DEBUG 17932 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] o.s.r2dbc.core.DefaultDatabaseClient     : Executing SQL statement [INSERT INTO foo_bar (foo) VALUES ($1)]
2022-12-08 16:32:13.149  INFO 17932 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] reactor.Flux.Iterable.1                  : | onComplete()
2022-12-08 16:32:13.149  INFO 17932 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] reactor.Flux.Iterable.1                  : | cancel()
2022-12-08 16:32:13.160 ERROR 17932 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] reactor.Flux.FlatMap.2                   : onError(org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: executeMany; SQL [INSERT INTO foo_bar (foo) VALUES ($1)]; Cannot exchange messages because the request queue limit is exceeded; nested exception is io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$RequestQueueException: [08006] Cannot exchange messages because the request queue limit is exceeded)
2022-12-08 16:32:13.167 ERROR 17932 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] reactor.Flux.FlatMap.2                   : 

org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: executeMany; SQL [INSERT INTO foo_bar (foo) VALUES ($1)]; Cannot exchange messages because the request queue limit is exceeded; nested exception is io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$RequestQueueException: [08006] Cannot exchange messages because the request queue limit is exceeded
    at org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.convertR2dbcException(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:215) ~[spring-r2dbc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.r2dbc.core.DefaultDatabaseClient.lambda$inConnectionMany$8(DefaultDatabaseClient.java:147) ~[spring-r2dbc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.lambda$onErrorMap$29(Flux.java:7105) ~[reactor-core-3.4.25.jar:3.4.25]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.lambda$onErrorResume$30(Flux.java:7158) ~[reactor-core-3.4.25.jar:3.4.25]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94) ~[reactor-core-3.4.25.jar:3.4.25]
```

I have tried to change the Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE, and also tried to add a concurrency value to the flatmap. It works when I reduced the value to `255` but I think it is not a good solution.